# Using matplotlib axvline with time object on x-axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am using `df.plot()` and my x-axis is a time object.

```
agg_df.index
Index(['00:00:00', '00:05:00', '00:10:00', '00:15:00', '00:20:00', '00:25:00',
       '00:30:00', '00:35:00', '00:40:00', '00:45:00',
       ...
       '23:10:00', '23:15:00', '23:20:00', '23:25:00', '23:30:00', '23:35:00',
       '23:40:00', '23:45:00', '23:50:00', '23:55:00'],
      dtype='object', length=288)
```

I am trying to use `axvline` and have tried passing both a string and a time object and neither works.  If I pass a string `axvline('18:00:00')` it draws a line but at `'00:00:00'`.  If I pass `axvline(dt.time(18,0))` I get the error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.time'
```

Comment: Convert your index to time objects, don’t leave as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure everything is a datetime object.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = [dt.date(2021, 1, 5), dt.date(2021, 2, 5), dt.date(2021, 3, 5)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(dates, [1, 2, 3])
plt.axvline(dt.date(2021, 2, 25), c='r')
plt.show()
```

Produces the following plot:
[image: sample_vline]